# Using a function for WsapiDataStore's filters config option

Tags: rally

Using SDK 2.0.

I need help figuring out a way to use a function in WsapiDataStore's 'filters:' config option.  When I run below code, I get errors.  If I remove 'filters:' option, no error.

I need to use a function since I have to check for one condition OR another.

Anyone have any idea how to get this working?

Thanks!

```
    Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    launch: function() {

        var features = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
            model: 'portfolioitem/feature',
            autoLoad: true,
            remoteSort: false,
            filters: [
                function (item) {
                return true;
                }
            ],
            listeners: {
                load: function(store, data, success) {
                    console.log('Store loaded in launch:', store);
                },
                scope: this
            }
        });             
    }
});
```

Here's the error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined sdk.js:4
a.define._createQueryString sdk.js:4
a.define.toString sdk.js:4
a.define.encodeFilters sdk.js:4
a.define.encodeFilters sdk.js:4
Ext.define.getParams sdk.js:4
Ext.define.buildRequest sdk.js:4
b.implement.callParent sdk.js:4
a.define.buildRequest sdk.js:4
Ext.define.doRequest sdk.js:4
Ext.define.read sdk.js:4
Ext.define.load sdk.js:4
b.implement.callParent sdk.js:4
Ext.define.load sdk.js:4
b.implement.callParent sdk.js:4
a.define.load sdk.js:4
b.implement.callParent sdk.js:4
a.define.load sdk.js:4
a.define.load.Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel.success sdk.js:4
b sdk.js:4
(anonymous function) sdk.js:4
d sdk.js:4
a.define._onTypeDefinitionsRetrieved sdk.js:4
a.define._fetchTypeDefinitions.Rally.environment.getIoProvider.httpGet.success sdk.js:4
Ext.apply.callback sdk.js:4
e sdk.js:4
Ext.apply.callback sdk.js:4
Ext.define.onComplete sdk.js:4
Ext.define.onStateChange sdk.js:4
(anonymous function) sdk.js:4
```

Comment: did u find an answer to this? I have the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

[Rally.data.QueryFilter](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p4/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.QueryFilter)

Along with this Stackoverflow Answer:

[Rally App SDK 2.0: Cannot modify QueryFilter object after initial creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804321/rally-app-sdk-2-0-cannot-modify-queryfilter-object-after-initial-creation)

Which shows a nice example of using Rally.data.QueryFilter to prepare an array of filters representing multiple conditions. You could wrap that logic up in a function and probably achieve your desired end result.