# Joined (AND and OR) Query Filters in App SDK2.0

Tags: rally

Using the 2.0p4 JavaScript SDK, I am trying to recreate a grid app I created previously using 1.30 JavaScript SDK, and am having problems creating a complex filter (with multiple ANDs and ORs).

Here is the query from the 1.30 version:

```
      function itemQuery() {
        var queryObject = {
        key: 'defect',
        type: 'defect',
         fetch: 'FormattedID,Name,State,ScheduleState,SupportNumber,OpenedDate,Priority,Rank,Severity,SubmittedBy,Owner,Iteration,Release,Project',
         query: '(((((SupportNumber contains "RNT") OR (SupportNumber contains "NS")) OR (SupportNumber contains ":")) OR (SupportNumber contains "CASE")) AND (State != Closed))',
         project: null
        };
```

So I querying for items that contains "RNT", ":", "NS", or "CASE" AND are not closed.
(SupportNumber is a custom field, which people have entered data in differently at different points)

And here is my App.js from the new version I am trying to create:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',

launch: function() {
    Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
        type: 'Defect',
        context: {
            workspace: 'workspace/12345',
            project: null,
        },
        success: function(model) {
            this.grid = this.add({
                xtype: 'rallygrid',
                model: model,
                columnCfgs: [
                    'FormattedID',
                    'Name',
                    'SupportNumber',
                    'Priority',
                    'Severity',
                    'State',
                    'Iteration',
                    'Release',
                    'Project',
                    'Owner',
                    'SubmittedBy'
                ],
                storeConfig: {
                    filters: [
                        {
                            property: 'State',
                            operator: '!=',
                            value: 'Closed'
                        },
                        {   
                            property: 'SupportNumber',
                            operator: 'contains',
                            value: 'RNT'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
        },
        scope: this
    });
}
```

});

I can see that just by adding filters to the config, you create ANDs, however I am lost in the documentation with how to create ANDs and ORs filters in the same config.....

Any direction anyone can give on how to create filter configs for App SDK 2.0, that use multiple ANDs and ORs, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out:

[Rally.data.QueryFilter](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p4/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.QueryFilter)

Along with this Stackoverflow Answer:

[Rally App SDK 2.0: Cannot modify QueryFilter object after initial creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804321/rally-app-sdk-2-0-cannot-modify-queryfilter-object-after-initial-creation)

Which shows a nice example of using Rally.data.QueryFilter to prepare an array of filters representing multiple conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! - But what is throwing me off is the comment in the documentation that "When used to filter a store, you don't have to create the object yourself, just pass in the filter config:" ... Then the example you linked to, and other examples in the documentation show ANDs and ORS by creating filter objects - but I don't see how you pass a filter config with multiple ANDs and ORs without creating a filter object.   Is it not possible?

Comment: I looked some more, and could not find any examples in which a filter config with multiple queries passed to a store. - Instead I ended up creating a filter object with multiple filters, and passed that to the store. ... My assumption is that the [example](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p4/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.QueryFilter) in which a config is passed in to the store is only when there are no OR filters for the config.  @mark-w

Comment: Correct - the default is to AND the conditions, so if you're using an OR you have to get more complex.